# glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE) vs. glDraw*(GL_LINE_STRIP...)

Tags: opengl, deprecated, glfw, opengl-3

I made an interesting, if confusing discovery today.

Thus far I've gotten by fine using `glDraw*(GL_LINE_STRIP...)` (or related `GL_LINE*` draw modes). Of course, this always requires some re-ordering of vertices in order to make the same vertex data work seamlessly between `GL_TRIANGLES` and `GL_LINE_STRIP`, but okay, all good there.

Then today I reintroduced some older code I had and found `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE)` among it. I looked it up and people were saying that while `GL_BACK` and `GL_FRONT` are deprecated in 3.3 core context, `glPolygonMode` is undeprecated, though supported only by `GL_FRONT_AND_BACK` as the first argument. So I tried it with `GL_LINE` as the second argument, along with `glDraw*(GL_TRIANGLES...)` and not only did it work perfectly, it also required none of the explicit re-ordering of vertices required to suit `GL_LINE_STRIP`. (I went back to an earlier configuration to test this).

Questions:

1. What am I supposed to be using, in 3.3 core context? Is either method OK? The reason I ask is that I am wondering whether the line `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);` is really even giving me a core profile, since it is after all only a hint to GLFW.
2. Which approach is recommended? Are there performance impacts to the latter? It certainly seems a lot more convenient.
3. Why even have `glDraw*(GL_LINE*...)` if this can be done via `glPolygonMode`?

Comment: 1: Both methods are ok in core profile. 3: Because you can also draw linestrips that do not form triangles, like a straight line or a circle etc.

Comment: @BDL Thanks! Care to put this in an answer? I don't mind about point 2; these that you've mentioned are sufficient.

Comment: Regarding point 2, `glPolygonMode (...)` *(as used in your question)* produces lines at the edges of polygons while keeping the primitive type a triangle. That has subtle implications for rasterization, clipping, texture mapping and other things that differ between triangle and line primitives. One could really ask why even have `glPolygonMode (...)` when you can do the same sort of thing with a geometry and fragment shader these days, it's convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad 1: Both methods are perfectly fine in OpenGL Core profile.

Ad 2: I'm not sure about this, but I guess that there will not be a huge performance difference.

Ad 3: This methods exist because one might also want to draw line objects that are not composed from triangles. Examples for this are circles or even straight lines.